# Cannot programmatically (jQuery/javascript) scroll page to top

Tags: validation, scroll, summary

Upon saving a rather long page, if view model has validation errors I want the focus to return to top of page.but it doesn't.

The validation summary is at the top of the view:

```
<div class="error" id="validationSummary">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6" id="bookmarker"> 
            @Html.ValidationSummary(False)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The save function is called via AJAX, then right after the AJAX function I've tried numerous scroll techniques:

```
 - $("#header").focus();
 - $("#validationSummary").focus();
 - $("body,html,document").scrollTop($("#validationSummary").offset().top);
```

...etc

I have this issue on numerous pages, but on some I've gotten it to work by nesting the validation summary inside more DIV tags.

In any case, I'm fairly stumped at this point, having sunk too many hours into trying this and that...any help/though would be a godsend.

Answer (score 0):

first youll need to set the focus of the page to the actual body and not a DIV. secondly you can use a javascript piece of code to navigate back to the top.

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)webapplication).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight 0)");
```

if you want more information and detail i have already posted a similar but more detailed answer here, though it was for c# the only piece of code you would need to edit is the way in which you write the SetFocus for the body of the page:

[Scroll into a Adobe Reader using buttons c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722365/scroll-into-a-adobe-reader-using-buttons-c-sharp/25683944#25683944)

hope this is of use for you. sorry i didnt realise this post was so long ago.