# Scroll into a Adobe Reader using buttons c#

Tags: c#, pdf, button, scroll

I Have Created a Simple form in which i have added Adobe Reader from toolbox using steps

1. right click in toolbox - Choose Items
2. choose COM Components tab and there "Adobe PDF Reader"
3. Now Drag&Drop the Adobe PDF Reader Control into an UserControl

I have successfully added this, opened up a pdf file also. Now it automatically provides with vertical scrollbars for scrolling through the pdf document.

What i want to achieve is instead of using the given scrollbars or mouse to scroll, i want to use a button to scroll scroll the pdf, So there will be two buttons, One for Scroll Up And the other for scroll down.

I have gone through many forums, pages, etc. Havnt found anythn that i could use.

I have Tried Simulating key presses with

```
SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}");
```

But as i press the button, the focus is lost on the adobe reader so it doesnt work

Pls help me... I have spent almost half a day searchin for a solution

Answer (score 1):

given that you have provided only a simple piece of code you have tried, i am going to try offer you a generic solution - where you will need to replace the specified variables:

- button names
- your web app name

as for first of the focus you need to specify where it will be, something along the lines of:

```
var pFocus = webapplication.formname.pdf_document.focus();
// or webapplication.focus(pdf_document);
```

again i am just writing this as an ideal layout as i have said you will need to replace the listed variables for this to work and possibly tweak the focus code as i haven't tested that - the buttons however provided you insert your variable names will work as i have tested these:

```
var buttonAction = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)webapplication).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight - 5)");
var buttonAction_2 = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)webapplication).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight 0)");
//button action will scroll to x co-ordinate 0(far left), y co-ordinate( 5px from bottom)
//buttonAction_2 will return you to the very top left of page, you can edit these values to mess around and try different settings.
```

so altogether it should look somewhat similar to (if you are using a method for the click just insert the code under there:

```
var pFocus = webapplication.formname.pdf_document.focus();

if (button.click = true)
webapplication = pFocus;

var buttonAction = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)webapplication).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight - 5)");

pFocus.execute(buttonAction);
```

then for button 2

```
var pFocus = webapplication.formname.pdf_document.focus();

if (button_2.click = true)
webapplication = pFocus;

 var buttonAction_2 = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)webapplication).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight 0)");

pFocus.execute(buttonAction_2);
```

hope this helps to some extent.

Comment: not sure if you even need the web application name after "IJavaScriptExecutor" but let me know how that goes - it probably works just as (IJavaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight 0)");